# GKE Ingress high latency with SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I've provision a GKE cluster and successfully deploy my web services. I also have the ingress deployed with the SSL Certificate imposed to expose the web services. After that, i've execute `time curl` and found out the latency of invoking the web service through ingress (HTTPS) is significantly higher compare to HTTP, Which is 10x higher.

- http - 10-20ms
- https - 120-200ms

It this something that us expected? as it costing too much for us for just to impose the SSL termination.

Here is the deployment yaml for ingress and services.

#### Ingress.yaml

```
piVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress 
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-service-ingress
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-service-ssl
  rules:
  - host: web.my-service.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

#### service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service 
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-service
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Interesting question. I will try to reproduce your scenario. Are you using [encrypted secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/)?

Comment: I've tested and for me worked without problem. What's is the region/availability zone you are using in GKE ?

Comment: Do you still have this problem ?
Can you answer MrKoopaKiller's question ?
Are you using  [GKE Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) or [NGINX Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) ?